# Do advanced actions count towards the attack limit?

Tags: song-of-ice-and-fire-rpg

**Q: Do all advanced actions** (*P173-174; Core Rulebook*) **count as an attack considering the limit of 1 attack per round per character?**

I had a long discussion with my group about whether or not actions like knockout, knockdown, disarm (*Advanced Actions P 173-174*) etc count towards the attack limit per round.

The reason that discussion started was that the Assist Action clearly states that it counts as an attack action and the said actions don't. Also Cautious Attack, Counterattack and Reckless Attack obviously modify the standard attack. The descriptions of knockout for example sounds like it is an attack.

> A well-placed blow can send your opponent into unconsciousness.

**Q: Are the Advanced Actions more like modifiers** *(Cautious Attack etc)* **and simple maneuvers which can be done in addition to a normal attack?**

> You may make only **one attack** in a round, regardless of action it
>   requires
>
> *Combat Structure (Step Four: Action P 162-163)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Knockdown and Knockout are not attacks

They are *Conflict Tests* (p. 29):

> Conflicts tests are used most commonly in combat, warfare, and intrigue. **A conflict test is always used to resolve anything that would function as an “attack.”** An attack might be a swing of a sword, sneaking past a guard, or using wiles to seduce a noble; effectively, anytime you would “do” something to someone else, you roll a conflict test. Unlike a basic test or competition test, where you are testing against the challenge and complexity of the action attempted, a conflict test pits your ability directly against your opponent. The Difficulty of these tests is your opponent’s Defense.

The bolded part is probably what caused this confusion. When introducing the rules, the system considers an "attack" whenever you roll against an opponent. But that is a more general rule, trying to explain what is a conflict for a first-time roleplayer, and not specifically related to combat. In combat, you are limited to *one* attack per round, but using the rules within the combat chapter, which says:

> There are several forms of attack as follows. You may make only one attack in a round, regardless of action it requires; to attack multiple opponents at once, use the divided attack or two-weapon attack options.

And then it lists those options:

- Standard Attack
- Divided Attack
- Two-Weapon Attack
- Combining Attacks

**Standard Attack** is simply the default and most common attack in combat (p. 163), but as pointed out by the **Assist** action, not the only form of attack. You have other attack options, like **Charge**, or advanced options (the problem here), like **Reckless Attack**, which is specifically named as an *attack*.

**Knockdown** does not say it's an attack. The description simply makes it clear that it is a *conflict test*:

> Using brute strength, you send your opponent crashing to the ground.
>   **Roll an Athletics test against your foe’s passive Agility result**.

Similarly, **Knockout** is also a *conflict test*:

> A well-placed blow can send your opponent into unconsciousness. You
>   may only use this maneuver against an unaware foe. **Roll a Fighting
>   test against your opponent’s passive Endurance result**.

But neither of them are *attacks*, as the combat chapter defines them.

### But Disarm is resolved as an attack

**Disarm**, on the other hand says:

> You may attempt to knock an opponent’s weapon from his hands. **Resolve
>   as a standard attack** except your Difficulty is equal to your opponent’s
>   passive Fighting result.

Since it's resolved as the standard attack, it should be considered an attack as well. Personally, I wouldn't classify a disarm attempt as an attack, especially considering how they are usually followed by an attack, but I can see why some GMs would consider it an attack and not allow another attack in the same round.